# VS Code and Python - Problem after installation (Path)

Tags: python, installation, settings

I'm planning to start learning Python and I have just installed it on my laptop.

Python 3.7.1 -> D:/Python/Python37

VS Code -> D:/Microsoft VS Code

I have also added the Python Microsoft extension within VS Code.

I'm trying to run the simplest function:

```
print ("Hello World!")
```

I do not understand why it returns me:

> PS C:\Users\raduf\OneDrive\Desktop\Python> cd 'C:\Users\raduf\OneDrive\Desktop\Python'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; &
>   'D:/Python/Python37/python.exe' 'c:\Users\raduf.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.11.0\pythonFiles\experimental\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '52090' 'c:\Users\raduf\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\hello.py'
>   Hello World

Why does it have to "cd" first that entire path? Any help is welcome!

Comment: Are you executing `print("Hello World!") directly into the command prompt? Or did you invoke Python first? Seems you aren't actually executing within python.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://python-forum.io/Thread-Error-in-VS-Code-after-installing

Answer (score 0):

Did you move the runtime files after installing them?

It looks like you are trying to run the things out of a local synced One Drive folder. Was the Python runtime also installed to that location?

In any case: your program works. The output you see is the command necessary to execute your program followed by its output, "Hello World" (without the quotes).

I am not sure about the CD part, but with the exception of the funky location, it looks to me like it's working as expected. :-)